# Binary Search Tree: Need to count the even Branches recursively

Tags: java

The issue with my code is that it is counting the leaf nodes, but I am not suppose to and I know i need to stop when root.left and root.right are null but not quite sure how to translate that into code.

Here is my code:

```
public int countEvenBranches() {
    return countEvenBranches(overallRoot);
}

private int countEvenBranches(IntTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (root.data % 2 == 1 ){
        return countEvenBranches(root.left) + countEvenBranches(root.right);
    } else {
        return 1 + countEvenBranches(root.left) + countEvenBranches(root.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is an even branch?  a branch with an even leaf?  can you give an example structure and what you expect as an answer?

Comment: Are you talking about a leaf node with even data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to find out if the left and right are null, then you can just do something like

```
if(root.left == null || root.right == null)
  return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help! i ended up figuring it out lol

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out. checking if root.left is equal to null and root.right is equal to null checks if the node has any children.

Here is the solution that works for all cases:

```
private int countEvenBranches(IntTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (root.data % 2 == 1 || root.left == null && root.right == null){
        return countEvenBranches(root.left) + countEvenBranches(root.right);
    } else {
        return 1 + countEvenBranches(root.left) + countEvenBranches(root.right);
    }
}
```